# how to get the value of foreign key in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with Laravel model relationships. I need to let users create new trucks. However, I need to store manufacturer's field as an id, not a title. So I decided to make two tables (manufacturers and trucks) that have one to many relationship (manufacturers have multiple trucks while one truck has one manufacturer).

Here's the migrations files.
Manufacturers table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('manufacturers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('manufacturer');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Trucks table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('trucks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('make_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('year');
        $table->string('owner');
        $table->unsignedInteger('owner_number')->nullable();
        $table->text('comments')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('make_id')->references('id')->on('manufacturers');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Manufacturer.php model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Manufacturer extends Model
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'manufacturers';

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'manufacturer', 
];

public function trucks(){
    return $this->hasMany(Truck::class);
}
}
```

Truck.php model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Truck extends Model
 {
 /**
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'trucks';

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'make_id', 'year', 'owner', 'owner_number', 'comments',
];

public function manufacturer(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Manufacturer::class);
}
}
```

Controller file:

```
public function index()
{
    $trucks = Truck::all();
    return view('trucks.index')->with('trucks', $trucks);
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach($trucks as $truck)
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$truck->make_id}}</td> //I need this one to show manufacturers title
                <td>{{$truck->year}}</td>
                <td>{{$truck->owner}}</td>
                <td>{{$truck->owner_number}}</td>
                <td>{{$truck->comments}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            @endforeach
```

This view now shows the id. What I need to do to show manufacturers title(manufacturers.manufacturer) instead of the id? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Try `{{$truck-> manufacturer->manufacturer }}`

Comment: @TalhaF. I did that, but it gives an error: Trying to get property 'manufacturer' of non-object. What to do??

Comment: In your controller change it to `$trucks = Truck::with('manufacturer')->all();`

Comment: @TalhaF. I really don't want to waste your time,but now it gives: BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()

Comment: @TalhaF. Change all() to get()... Truck::with('manufacturer')->get()

Comment: @nikistag still getting the same: Trying to get property 'manufacturer' of non-object

Comment: @TalhaF.  In your models add the foreign key like (Manufacturer::class, 'make_id' ), on both

Comment: @nikistag you mean (Manufacturer::class, 'make_id' ) and (Truck::class, 'make_id' ) or (Manufacturer::class, 'make_id' ) and Truck::class, 'id')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key for manufacturer in trucks table is not manufacturer_id. In this case you need to declare it in your models:

```
return $this->belongsTo(Manufacturer::class, 'make_id' )
```

And

```
 return $this->hasMany(Truck::class, 'make_id' )
```